# android:making user to select a date only in a range of time period

Tags: android, validation, android-datepicker

I want user to select a date within that month only and also not less than current date.

For example: If the day is 18th march 13 then user shud only select any date from 18th march to 31st march '13. Also I have two buttons for choosing "from date" and "to date" which use the same listener for datepicker.I have tried different solutions already suggested on this site but they are not compatible in this case. If I am using the suggested code im loosing the functionality of using same datepicker listener for both buttons. I tried the below code but it's not working.

```
public class Leave_form extends Activity 
{


    private static EditText tvDislpayResult;
    private Button startPickDate;
    private Button endPickDate;
    private Calendar startDate;
    private Calendar endDate;
    //private EditText startDateDisplay;
    //private EditText endDateDisplay;
    static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;
    private TextView startDateDisplay;
    private TextView endDateDisplay;
    private TextView activeDateDisplay;
    private Calendar activeDate;



    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_leave_form);

        /*  capture our View elements for the start date function   */
        startDateDisplay = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.e_from_date);
        startPickDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Set_date1);

        /* get the current date */
        startDate = Calendar.getInstance();

        /* add a click listener to the button   */
        startPickDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                showDateDialog(startDateDisplay, startDate);
            }
        });

        /* capture our View elements for the end date function */
        endDateDisplay = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.e_to_date);
        endPickDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Set_date2);

        /* get the current date */
        endDate = Calendar.getInstance();

        /* add a click listener to the button   */
        endPickDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                showDateDialog(endDateDisplay, endDate);
            }
        });

        /* display the current date (this method is below)  */
       // updateDisplay(startDateDisplay, startDate);
       // updateDisplay(endDateDisplay, endDate);
    }

    private void updateDisplay(TextView dateDisplay, Calendar date) {
        dateDisplay.setText(
                new StringBuilder()
                    // Month is 0 based so add 1
                    .append(date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) ).append("-")
                    .append(date.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1).append("-")
                    .append(date.get(Calendar.YEAR)).append(" "));

    }

    public void showDateDialog(TextView dateDisplay, Calendar date)
    {
       activeDateDisplay = dateDisplay;
        activeDate = date;
        showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
    }

    private OnDateSetListener dateSetListener = new OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) 
         {

             try {
                    Date selectedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd").parse(year+"/"+monthOfYear+"/"+dayOfMonth);
                    Date currDate = new Date();
                    if(selectedDate.compareTo(currDate ) >=0 )
                        {
                          activeDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                          activeDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                          activeDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                          updateDisplay(activeDateDisplay, activeDate);
                          unregisterDateDisplay();

                        }
                    else
                        {
                         //show message
                        }

              }
              catch(Exception e)
              {
                  e.getMessage();

               }
                   }
    };

    private void unregisterDateDisplay() {
        activeDateDisplay = null;
        activeDate = null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
            case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
                return new DatePickerDialog(this, dateSetListener, activeDate.get(Calendar.YEAR), activeDate.get(Calendar.MONTH), activeDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) {
        super.onPrepareDialog(id, dialog);
        switch (id) {
            case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
                ((DatePickerDialog) dialog).updateDate(activeDate.get(Calendar.YEAR), activeDate.get(Calendar.MONTH), activeDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
                break;
        }
    }

    public void leave(View view)
    {
        Intent intent1=new Intent(this,Rough.class);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_rough);
        startActivity(intent1);


    }



}
```